# How to trigger Jenkins pipeline from Jira transitions using Issue key, which is mentioned in Bitbucket's repository commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jira

Okay, the title of the question maybe confusing or meaningless. So, explaining it in detail:
I have Jira, Bitbucket and Jenkins. All were integrated.

1. I have a project called "ABC" in Bitbucket, which has 15 repositories(Java microservices).
2. I have 15 separate Jenkins pipelines for each repository and a Master Pipeline which can trigger the Microservice pipelines (If parameters passed either bitbucket commit id or some others..)
3. I have a workflow in Jira, which has 'deploy' transition, which can trigger Jenkins pipeline(any of them if configured) along with parameter Jira_ID(jira issue key).

Now, the question is.. How to trigger the latest code commit repository pipeline, but only after Jira deploy transition. [Answer may lies in between JiraID to be mentioned in repository commit.. or some other].
I have been on this for past 1month but no luck, please help..

Answer (score 0):

I would try to configure a webhook in Jira for the transition event.

And use the generic webhook trigger-plugin for Jenkins to receive the webhook.